# how to get Full Path if image to send to server by MultiPart in Android

Tags: android, image, filepath

In My App, user can take Picture from **Camera** Or Select from **Gallery** And Crop It to send to server. So there is No Problem.,
Problem is when user **select picture from Gallery**

**URI path from camera cropped :** /mnt/sdcard/avatar_1434958340804.jpg 
**URI path from Storage cropped :** /external/images/media/19

**Error:**

> IOException : /external/images/media/19: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory)

Comment: The /external directory is just wrong.  Why do you think that should be the URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get path from URI. Use below function:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        //Log.e("in","conversion"+contentURI.getPath());
       String path;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                   .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null); 
        if (cursor == null) 
            path=contentURI.getPath();

        else {
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
            path=cursor.getString(idx);

        }
        if(cursor!=null)
            cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` is depricated. This no longer workes now

Answer (score 0):

URI path from camera cropped : **/mnt/sdcard/avatar_1434958340804.jpg**

URI path from Storage cropped : **/external/images/media/19**

After API 19 the content URI changed

**content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A151323**

and

**/storage/3437-6630/Pics/IMG_5737.JPG**

Before API19 the Calling the gallery Intent It'll Lead to Gallery.But **After API 19** it will lead to call images. From here you can go to Gallery or External Storage or Google drive. so there is chance to get a **RuntimeException**.

> MainActivity.java

```
       String realPath =" ";
       try {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
        }catch (RuntimeException e){
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
        }
```

> In RealPathUtil.java

**getRealPathFromURI()**

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context,Uri contentURI) {
    //Log.e("in","conversion"+contentURI.getPath());
    String path;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        path=contentURI.getPath();

    else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        path=cursor.getString(idx);

    }
    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.close();
    Log.e("GGGG CCC ",path);
    return path;
}
```

**getRealPathFromURI_API19**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    int columnIndex = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
    }

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.e("GGGGG FilePath",filePath);
    return filePath;
}
```